# Is there anyway to patch /apex using Magisk?

Tags: root-access, magisk

As part of Project Mainline, Google decided to pack a number of files in `.apex` modules which are located in `/system/apex` which upon boot, are extracted and mounted in `/apex`.

For example: the contents of `/system/apex/com.android.tzdata.apex` file will be mounted at: `/apex/com.android.tzdata`

Is there any way for patching (overriding) the contents of mounted `.apex` files using Magisk?

Comment: Do `mount --bind`. See [mount(8) manual page](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/mount.8.html).